# Two variable perturbation analysis of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

I have following set of equations,

$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=k z(t) - 3 k y(t) - y(t)^2 + \epsilon_1 (M-z(t))^2$

$\epsilon_2 \frac{dz(t)}{dt}=Mz(t) - z(t) y(t) - 2 \epsilon_2 y(t) + 2 \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 (M-z(t))^2$

From above, I can't even solve the unperturbed problem if the perturbation is around only one of the $\epsilon_1$ or $\epsilon_2$.

Now my question is: Is it possible to do perturbation theory for two small parameters and not just one?

One more thing to note is: the equations are singular for $\epsilon_2$ but regular for $\epsilon_1$.

Any suggestion, reference or help on how to go about solving these equations will be of great help.

Comment: The solutions for $ϵ_1=ϵ_2=0$ are the constant solution $y=M$, $z=3M+M^2/k$ and $z=0$, $3ky(t)^{-1}+1=(3ky(0)^{-1}+1)e^{3kt}$.